# Problema de consulta PDO y Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

tengo un problema al realizar la consulta no me devuelve nada. La consulta es correcta ya que la he ejecutado en el sqldeveloper y  tampoco me da error en la conexión. Este es mi código:

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>MUNICIPIOS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include_once('php/clases.php');
    $bd = new ConexionBD();
    $consulta = 'SELECT * FROM MUNICIPIOS';
    $res = $bd->consulta($consulta);

    foreach($res as $fila){
        print_r($fila);
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

clases.php

```
<?php

class ConexionBD{
    private $conexion;
    private $host = "oci:dbname=localhost/XE";
    private $usuario = "BD";
    private $pass = "1234";

    function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->conexion = new PDO($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->pass);
            $this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Conexion realizada con exito!<br>";
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->conexion = null;
            $codigo = $e->getCode();
            $mensaje = $e->getMessage();
            $fichero = $e->getFile();
            $linea = $e->getLine();
            echo "Error en la conexion! <br>
            Mensaje de error: $mensaje<br>
            Codigo: $codigo<br>
            Fichero: $fichero<br>
            Linea: $linea";
        }
    }

    function consulta($query){
        try {
            $stmt= $this->conexion->query($query);
            echo "Consulta realizada con exito!<br>";
        }catch( PDOException $e ){
            $stmt = null;
            $codigo = $e->getCode();
            $mensaje = $e->getMessage();
            $fichero = $e->getFile();
            $linea = $e->getLine();
            echo "Error en la consulta! <br>
                Mensaje de error: $mensaje<br>
                Codigo: $codigo<br>
                Fichero: $fichero<br>
                Linea: $linea";
        }
        return $stmt;
    }

    function ejecuta($query){
        try {
            $stmt= $this->conexion->exec($query);
        }catch( PDOException $e ){
            $stmt = null;
            $codigo = $e->getCode();
            $mensaje = $e->getMessage();
            $fichero = $e->getFile();
            $linea = $e->getLine();
            echo "Error en la ejecucion! <br>
                Mensaje de error: $mensaje<br>
                Codigo: $codigo<br>
                Fichero: $fichero<br>
                Linea: $linea";
        }
        return $stmt;
    }

    function consultaPaginada($consulta, $page_num, $page_size){
    try{
        $first = ($page_num - 1) * $page_size + 1;
        $last = $page_num * $page_size;
        $paged_query = "SELECT * FROM  ( SELECT ROWNUM RNUM, AUX.*  FROM( $consulta) AUX WHERE ROWNUM <= :last) WHERE  RNUM >= :first";
        $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare($paged_query);
        $stmt->bindParam( ':first', $first );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':last', $last );
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }catch( PDOException $e ) {
        $stmt = null;
        $codigo = $e->getCode();
        $mensaje = $e->getMessage();
        $fichero = $e->getFile();
        $linea = $e->getLine();
        echo "Error en la consulta! <br>
            Mensaje de error: $mensaje<br>
            Codigo: $codigo<br>
            Fichero: $fichero<br>
            Linea: $linea";
    }
    }


}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu función `consulta` tú no estás devolviendo una representación de los datos, la cual se obtiene aplicando algún método `fetch` al `$stmt` que ha resultado de tu consulta. Si modificas dicha función de la siguiente forma debería funcionar:

```
function consulta($query){
        $stmt= $this->conexion->query($query);
        //echo "Consulta realizada con exito!<br>";
    if ($stmt){
        $arrResultado =$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }else{
        $errInfo=$this->conexion->errorInfo();
        $arrResultado=array("Error"=>"Error en la consulta! <br>
            Mensaje de error: $errInfo[2]<br>
            Codigo: $errInfo[0]");
    }
    return $arrResultado;
}
```

Lo que he hecho ha sido básicamente construir un array con datos válidos, en caso de que la consulta obtenga resultados, o construir un array con un mensaje de error en el caso de fallo. Devolviendo al final ese array y no el `$stmt`, el cual es un puntero, sobre los resultados, el cual hay que leer de alguna manera. En este caso he usado `fetchAll`, pero puedes usar cualquier otro método que te convenga.

En la edición, he usado el método `errorInfo` de PDO, para obtener los mensajes de error, tal y como indica el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php).

Comment: Buenas, gracias por su tiempo. He realizado ese cambio pero sigue sin funcionar,  no me devuelve ningún resultado :(

Comment: @JosManuelGonzlezGutirrezjm prueba con la nueva edición del código. Al establecer esto en tu conexión: `$this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` ya no tienes que usar `try... catch` cada vez que vayas a usar ese objeto, puedes capturar los errores de una forma más simple, con un `if` por ejemplo, como he hecho, en caso de que la variable `$stmt` sea `FALSE` (indicio de que algo funcionó mal). Entonces ahí puedes acudir a `errorInfo` para obtener el error. He ignorado el intento de `getFile` y `getLine`, pues no aplican a objetos PDO...